# Show multiple option in URL with Redux framework in front end

Tags: theme-options, framework

I'm creating a WordPress theme in which I'm using the Redux Framework for creating the theme's options page.

I want to show multiple blog layouts without creating custom WP templates. I saw in many themes the URL is something like

- theme.com?home_layout=grid&sidebar=left
- theme.com?home_layout=list&sidebar=none

Now in the theme-option file i've got this one for the sidebar:

```
array(
'id'       => 'sidebar_position',
'type'     => 'select',
'title'    => esc_html__( 'Blog sidebar', 'omio' ),
'options'  => array(
    'left' => esc_html__('Left', 'omio'),
    'right' => esc_html__('Right', 'omio'),
    'disable' => esc_html__('Disable', 'omio'),
),
'default'  => 'right' ),
```

Now in the functions.php i've made a GET request code but didn't work.

```
$sidebar = isset( $_GET['sidebar_position'] ) ? $_GET['sidebar_position'] : 'right';

switch ( $sidebar ) {

case 'left':
set_theme_mod( 'sidebar_position', 'left' );
break;

case 'disable':
set_theme_mod( 'sidebar_position', 'disable' );
break;

default:
set_theme_mod( 'sidebar_position', 'right' ); }
```

How to do it, please :)
for example when I put the sidebar at the left (theme.com/?sidebar=left) nothing happen, sidebar stay by default at the right

Comment: what does it mean "but didn't work"? software always does something if it runs the code, or it do not run the code at all. Edit and describe what does happen and what have you done to debug.

Comment: Hello Mark, for example when I put the sidebar at the left (theme.com/?sidebar=left) nothing happen, sidebar still by default at the right

Comment: so maybe the problem is with your front end generation part of the code?

Comment: How to fix it? can you please help me

Comment: DId you notice you are passing the variable "sidebar" in URL but you are checking for "sidebar_position" in your function.

Comment: Yes, Robert, even with sidebar_position in URL still not working

Comment: suggest you add to the question the styles that you are outputting that make the sidebar display in different positions

Comment: link.com/?sidebar_position=left like this? that's also not working

Comment: can someone fix it for me? i'll send the theme

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
function tes_sidebar() {
    global $redux_demo;
    $sidebar =& $redux_demo['sidebar_position'] ) ? $redux_demo['sidebar_position'] : 'right';
    switch ( $sidebar ) {
        case 'left':
        get_template_part( 'sidebar','left' );
        break;
        case 'disable':
        get_template_part( '' );
        break;
        default:
        get_template_part( 'sidebar','right' );
        break;
    }
}
```

call with this function: `tes_sidebar();`

Answer (score 0):

You also wrong pass parameter $_GET method

$_GET method get parameter value in Url

```
$sidebar = isset($_GET['sidebar'] ) ?  $_GET['sidebar'] : 'right';

switch ( $sidebar ) {

 case 'left':
 set_theme_mod( 'sidebar_position', 'left' );
 break;


  case 'disable':
  set_theme_mod( 'sidebar_position', 'disable' );
  break;

 default:
 set_theme_mod( 'sidebar_position', 
  'right' );
 }
```